# npm update fires off successfully, but doesn't actually upgrade npm -v

Tags: node.js, npm

This is on a Macbook

I execute `sudo npm install -g npm` and get this following output:

`/Users/myUser/.npm-packages/bin/npm -> /Users/myUser/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@3.10.8 /Users/myUser/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm`

However, when I restart terminal and `npm -v`, I still get 2.15.9

Comment: I think the issue here is that you have update your `npm` version globally (with sudo). If you run `sudo npm -v`, is the version still the same?

Answer (score 0):

The `nvm` tool is most commonly used for managing Node versions and upgrades.  Follow the directions here for your platform: https://github.com/creationix/nvm